# almost magic unitary

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, quantum-groups

A magic unitary is a unitary matrix $u=(p_{ij})_{ij}$ whose entries are all projections (in some Hilbert space) and in each row they sum to the identity and same holds for each column $(\sum_i p_{ij}=1=\sum_j p_{ij})$. My question is, if there is a sequence of "almost magic unitaries", by which I mean matrices $u_k=(q_{ij}^k)$ whose entries are all projections BUT they only sum to identity in each row and NOT in each column but close to identity ($\sum_j q_{ij}^k=1$ and for each j, $\sum_i ||q_{ij}^k-1||_2\rightarrow 0$) such that $u_k\rightarrow u$ in $||.||_2$ norm, Can one find actual magic unitaries that are close to this "almost magic unitaries" which approximate the original magic unitary?

It's similar to finding an orthogonal set of projections summing to identity from  a set of almost orthogonal positive operators almost adding up to the identity.

Comment: Are these matrices square? finite?

Comment: Could you clarify what the norm $\|\cdot\|_2$ is?

Comment: These matrices are all square matrices. The $||.||_2$ norm is the trace norm (Frobenius norm) $||x||_2=\sqrt {tr(xx^*)}$. Here we are assuming the projections live in a finite dimensional Hilbert space where the "tr"(trace functional) makes sense.

Comment: Maybe you can check this article https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.04912 They construct magic unitaries (aka quantum permutation matrices) on a computer by taking _some_ set of projections and then orthonormalizing the rows and then the columns and then over and onver. This way they obtain exactly a sequence you are talking about I guess.